# Align text with mPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using WriteText() from mPDF https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/writetext.html but I am not getting around of how to center the text. Currently the format is L-to-R. How do I Center it?

```
<?php
use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

require_once('FPDI/autoload.php');
require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php'); 
require_once('FPDI/Fpdi.php'); 

$pdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

$pdf->AddPage(); 

$pdf->setSourceFile('PDF/Sample.pdf'); 

$pdf->WriteText(20, 20, "This is a text");

//rest of code
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Increase the first parameter of WriteText until you text is written in the center of the area you want. This either requires to guess the width of the text and the area, or calculating it.
2. Use another method of writing text. Either use HTML/CSS or [WriteCell()](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/writecell.html) or [MultiCell()](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/multicell.html) which have a parameter to align text inside a specified boundary.